# Can't create an internal NLB load balancer for ingress-nginx ingress controller for EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, ingress-nginx, aws-nlb

Tried various annotations including the following one (based on https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx#additional-internal-load-balancer). But the load balancer which is intended to be internal is created for Service ingress-nginx-controller-internal as Internet-facing (but supposed to be Internal) in AWS each time:

```
controller:
  service:
    external:
      enabled: true
      ...

    internal:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internal"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

Comment: If you're using the AWS LB Controller to provision the NLB, it will create an internal LB be default. You don't have to use the aws-load-balancer-scheme annotation. I would also have a look at this issue, https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/3340.